# NHibernate ByteCode providers source

Tags: nhibernate

Where can I get`NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory` source ? It was in NHibernate repository, but was removed about month ago. Where is it now ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NHibernate are no longer maintaining ByteCode providers as of the 3.2 release, as NHibernate will now come with a built-in proxy factory based on LinFu.

You can get the source if you check out or browse a previous version of the NH repository (3.1 or earlier).

I have started maintaining a copy of the ByteCode providers for new versions of NHibernate here: https://github.com/SimonBartlett/NHibernate.ByteCode